# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\pathto\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im having an issue with Selenium on Python 3.

Here is the code:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

 import time
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

 options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
 options.binary_location = '/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome'
 service_log_path = "{}/chromedriver.log".format
 service_args = ['--verbose']
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Funky\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe',
     options=options,
     service_args=service_args,
     service_log_path=service_log_path)
```

here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\funky\Desktop\Projects\JS Parser 2.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Funky\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe',
  File "C:\Users\funky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\funky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Users\funky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Users\Funky\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What is this meant to do: `service_log_path = "{}/chromedriver.log".format`? You're supposed to supply a path, not a function -- as far as I can tell from the documentation.

Comment: Seems this status code is returned sometimes with older chromedriver and/or Chrome versions. Unless you have reason to use the older versions, you might consider upgrading to see if that would solve the issue.

Comment: `format()` what?